# Blackberry Field alignment in a VerticalFieldManager

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to add two fields in a vertical field manager. I want the first one to be align on the left and the second one (on the second line) on the right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the style argument of the field constructor to specify alignment, both horizontal and vertical.

```
    VerticalFieldManager titlevfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
    LabelField leftField = new LabelField("my label", Field.FIELD_LEFT);
    LabelField rightField = new LabelField("right field", Field.FIELD_RIGHT);
    titlevfm.add(leftField);
    titlevfm.add(rightField);
```

Comment: The VerticalFieldManager should be defined with style value USE_ALL_WIDTH.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a class that extends Manager class
Override the sublayout method and place contents as per your choice