# Aligning fields in VerticalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, jde, rim-4.3

I'm trying to develop a stock ticker in JDE 4.3.

I found in a recent post that it is possible for two(2) fields to be aligned both horizontal and vertical: [Blackberry Field alignment in a VerticalFieldManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486664/blackberry-field-alignment-in-a-verticalfieldmanager).

My question is: is it possible to align horizontally (3) or more ActiveRichTextFields horizontally maybe even five fields? I already have a function that can auto-smooth scroll a VerticalFieldManager

Comment: Are you trying to align them in a grid layout (rows and columns of these fields) or are you just trying to get a long "row" of fields?

Comment: Thanks Eric for you response, really appreciate it. I'm trying to align them as a long row of fields within a VerticalFieldManager.. if ever that's possible.

Answer (score -1):

nevermind.. i was using the wrong manager. HorizontalFieldManager does the the trick.